# Почему "$ telnet www.google.com 80" подсвечивается как ошибка в среде разработки?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Данный код в `PyCharm` подсвечивается как ошибка, как это исправить?

`lesson1.py`:

```
$ telnet www.google.com 80
```

Comment: Добавляйте код, а не ссылку на скриншот кода. Опишите проблему более подробно: что хотите сделать, что не получается.

Comment: там ссылка на ошибку и код,Вот код - $ telnet www.google.com 80;

Comment: у меня подчеркивает все красным и ничего не работает,аналогично и с другими библиотеками

Comment: где вы прочитали / с чего вы взяли, что это будет работать?

Comment: Код нужно добавлять в вопрос, а не в комментарий, для этого есть кнопка "править"

Answer (score 7):

Нельзя в коде на Python писать команды, которые вы пишете в командной строке.

Чтобы выполнить такие команды в Python нужно вызывать их специальным методом:

```
import subprocess

result = subprocess.run(["telnet", "www.google.com", "80"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

# на экране будет выведен результат работы команды
# и информация об объекте result (экземпляр класса CompletedProcess)
print(result, dir(result))
```

Более подробно про запуск команд из кода на Python можно прочитать в официальной документации для модуля [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html).

Comment: и вместо внешней команды, можно socket, telnetlib, `urlopen()` в зависимости от потребностей использовать.